# Why are my counts different when using CASE operator VS IF function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I learnt that the difference between CASE and IF statement is as follows *"IF is a CASE with only one 'WHEN' statement"*. But I got confused when querying this:

I have the table Olympics which contains the countries and medals associated to it. I am counting the total number of medals won by each country. The first query results in the correct output but second query does not. Can anyone tell the reason why case-when and if statement are working differently here?

**First query**

```
select
    NOC,
    COUNT(IF (medal = "GOLD", medal, NULL)) as GOLD,
    COUNT(IF (medal = "SILVER", medal, NULL)) as SILVER,
    COUNT(IF (medal = "BRONZE", medal, NULL)) as BRONZE
from olympics 
group by NOC;
```

| NOC | GOLD | SILVER | BRONZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARG | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| ARM | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| AUS | 1 | 1 | 1 |

**Second query**

```
select NOC,
count(case when MEDAL='GOLD' then '1' ELSE 0 end) as GOLD,
count(case when MEDAL='SILVER' then '1'  ELSE 0 end) as SILVER,
count(case when MEDAL='BRONZE' then '1' ELSE 0 end) as BRONZE
from olympics 
group by NOC
```

| NOC | GOLD | SILVER | BRONZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARG | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ARM | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| AUS | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `COUNT()` incorrect because `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Your expressions always return a non-`NULL` value, so all three values would be the same.

If you are using `COUNT()`, `ELSE` needs to be `NULL` for it to work:

```
count(case when MEDAL = 'GOLD' then 1 end) as GOLD,
```

(The default is `NULL`.)

Alternatively, you could use `SUM()`.

I removed the single quotes.  It doesn't matter what is being counted.  This is Standard SQL, hence recommended (in my opinion) over using the bespoke `IF()` extension in MySQL.

If you are going to use a SQL extension, you might as well use a more convenient one:

```
sum( MEDAL = 'GOLD' ) as GOLD
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.